# Approximation of e^-x not returning the proper value

Tags: c

**N.b.** The below code is deliberately done without using the library `<math.h>`

To calculate the approximation of:

[image: Text]

I need to work with the following formula:

[image: Text]

I just wrote the below code to do just that, but I am missing something that I can't figure out that makes the code not to return the proper value. It would be great if somebody could take a look. Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f_fact(float i);
double f_pot (float i, float x);

int main()
{
   double f_calculo, a, x, i;

   printf("Please specify the number of terms to sum\n");
   scanf("%lf", &a);

   printf("Please enter the value of the exponent\n");
   scanf("%lf", &x);

   for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
   {
      f_calculo = f_calculo + (double) f_pot (i, x) / f_fact(i);
   }

   printf("The result is: %lf\n", f_calculo);

   return 0;
}

double f_fact(float i)
{
   int j;
   long long int factorial = 1;

   for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
   {
      factorial = factorial * j;
   }
   return (factorial);
}


double f_pot (float i, float x)
{
   int j;
   double power = 1;

   for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
   {
      power = power * (-x);
   }
   return (power);
}
```

Comment: I removed the "e" tag (it doesn't refer to the mathematical constant).

Comment: What value is your code printing and what value do you expect instead? A `double` can only hold a fixed number of bits, precision is limited.

Comment: You declared `f_calculo`, but you didn't initialize it. Please enable your compiler warnings.

Comment: Also, you know you're computing `e^(-x)` instead of `e^x`, and you are actually going to get `e^(-x)-1` because you are omitting the `x^0` term.

Comment: Are you required to write and use `f_fact` and `f_pot` or are you allowed to evaluate the approximation in a different (and more efficient) way?

Comment: @NateEldredge You are completely right! I just added `1 +` to the print statement: `printf("The result is: %lf\n", 1 + f_calculo);` and now I get the correct results! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leaving below the final corrected code based on @NateEldredge comments. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f_fact(float i);
double f_pot (float i, float x);

int main()
{
   double f_calculo, k, x, i;

   printf("Please specify the number of terms to sum (k)\n");
   scanf("%lf", &k);

   printf("Please enter the value of the exponent (x)\n");
   scanf("%lf", &x);

   for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
   {
      f_calculo = f_calculo + (double) f_pot (i, x) / f_fact(i);
   }

   printf("The result is: %lf\n", 1 + f_calculo);

   return 0;
}

double f_fact(float i)
{
   int j;
   long long int factorial = 1;

   for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
   {
      factorial = factorial * j;
   }
   return (factorial);
}


double f_pot (float i, float x)
{
   int j;
   double power = 1;

   for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
   {
      power = power * (-x);
   }
   return (power);
}
```