# Skewed results when values go over the memory threshold

Tags: c, memory

**N.b.** The below code is deliberately done without using the library `<math.h>`

**N.b. 1** I posted earlier another question about this code, but was covering a different issue. This is the other question: [Approximation of e^-x not returning the proper value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602235/approximation-of-e-x-not-returning-the-proper-value)

To calculate the approximation of:

[image: Text]

I need to work with the following formula:

[image: Text]

I just wrote the below code to do just that.

However, I see that when I try with large values for `k`, I start getting inaccurate results. For instance, when plugging in `x=2` and `k>=40` to get the value of `e^-2` I don't see the correct results, but with `x=2` and `12<k<40`, all seems fine and I get the proper value: 0.135335. I understand this is due to the memory allocated to the values that act as numerator and denominator, but my questions are:

- The most I can do to fix this is to use `Long double`? And even then, I guess there is a memory limit again.
- How can I identify at which `k` value the memory is not enough and the results start to become inaccurate? This is so that I can prevent the user from entering `k` values that go over that threshold.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f_fact(float i);
double f_pot (float i, float x);

int main()
{
   double f_calculo, k, x, i;

   printf("Please specify the number of terms to sum (k)\n");
   scanf("%lf", &k);

   printf("Please enter the value of the exponent (x)\n");
   scanf("%lf", &x);

   for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
   {
      f_calculo = f_calculo + (double) f_pot (i, x) / f_fact(i);
   }

   printf("The result is: %lf\n", 1 + f_calculo);

   return 0;
}

double f_fact(float i)
{
   int j;
   long long int factorial = 1;

   for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
   {
      factorial = factorial * j;
   }
   return (factorial);
}


double f_pot (float i, float x)
{
   int j;
   double power = 1;

   for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
   {
      power = power * (-x);
   }
   return (power);
}


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602235/approximation-of-e-x-not-returning-the-proper-value
```

Comment: Use arrays, and roll your own float operations (then you can achieve whatever precision you want as long as you have enough memory) Warning: very slow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Approximation of e^-x not returning the proper value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602235/approximation-of-e-x-not-returning-the-proper-value)

Comment: @jwdonahue does not appear to be a duplicate. The one you cited is about not returning correct value, while this one is about not enough precision. They are totally different questions and have totally different solutions

Comment: Consider a [bignum library](https://gmplib.org) that can give you whatever precision you require.

Comment: Factorials get very big very fast. The `f_fact` function is calculating the factorial using `long long int`. That will only work for `i` up to 20. You'll have better results if you declare `factorial` as a `double`.

Comment: @user12986714, considering they are using exactly the same code, I think it's safe to assume that they have the same set of bugs.

Comment: @jwdonahue no it is not after close examination. This question does not contain any bug; only need more precision in float operations.

Comment: The correct way to compute a series is to A) compute the terms incrementally, and B) add the terms starting with the smallest. Incrementally means that if you know `term[k]`, then `term[k+1] = term[k] * (-x) / (k+1)`. And adding from smallest to largest means storing the terms in an array until you've computed the smallest term.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  The OP posted exactly the same code in two different posts (with one variable name change).  The questions may be different, but that may just be because the OP has ignored good advice on how to fix the bug in their code.  The use of uninitialized `f_calculo` is a bug.  It's pointless to discuss any other issues with this code, until that is fixed.

Comment: @Henry, was your previous question on this code answered satisfactorily? If so, either mark the answer or add it yourself and mark it.  I still think you're using a variable before it's initialized.  Could be you have a compiler switch that clears your stack memory before use, but the code is exploiting undefined behavior.

Comment: @jwdonahue although this question and the other you mention share the same code, are covering different topics so they need different answers. That is why I kept them separate. Just added in the other question the final answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About the first question:**

Yes, `long double` would increase the accuracy but also has its limits. So if you need more precision, you would have to implement your own datatype... (as mentioned in the comments)

**Second Question**
You could add a check for the limits, included in `limits.h`

```
#include <limits.h>
printf("The minimum value of LONG = %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
printf("The maximum value of LONG = %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
```

Comment: Thanks for this @lx76. That will certainly help me! :-)